# XML-Schema key/keyref issue

Tags: xml, xsd

Given the following xml-snippet:

```
<Environment>
...
    <MySqlConfiguration>
      <ActiveServer>1@db1</ActiveServer>
      <PassiveServer>2@db1</PassiveServer>
      <Replicate from="1@db1" to="2@db1" />
      <Replicate from="2@db1" to="1@db1" />
    </MySqlConfiguration>
...
</Environment>
```

I want to restrict from/to values to those specified in ActiveServer or PassiveServer

in XSD, I try the following:

```
 <xs:element name="Environment" type="environment" >
    <xs:key name="ServerKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//ActiveServer|PassiveServer"/>
      <xs:field xpath="*"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="ServerKeyRef" refer="ServerKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Replicate"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@from"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    ...
  </xs:element>
```

However, the `xpath="*"` field selector in the key does not work (it does not get the text node of the Active/PassiveServer elements). `xpath="text()"` does not work either.  Doing something like:

```
<xs:element name="Environment" type="environment" >
    <xs:key name="ServerKey">
      <xs:selector xpath="Environment"/>
      <xs:field xpath="ActiveServer|PassiveServer"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="ServerKeyRef" refer="ServerKey">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Replicate"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@from"/>
    </xs:keyref>
    ...
  </xs:element>
```

Does not work (field must refer to one instance; specifying just one of those would work).

Is there some way I'm overlooking on how to grab an element's text content in a field xpath value?

Comment: Okay, so it looks like I can use `xpath="."` for the field value of the key... HOWEVER, the selector expression `xpath=".//ActiveServer|PassiveServer"`  only matches the first of either element name (not first occurrence, first match), so keyref will not be valid if it contains `"2@db1"` as a value, even though it's specified in PassiveServer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the following to work:

```
  <xs:selector xpath=".//ActiveServer|.//PassiveServer"/>
  <xs:field xpath="."/>
```

Note "|" has lowest precedence so the ".//" needs to be repeated. The BNF from XSD Rec:

```
 Selector  ::=  Path ( '|' Path )*
```